# Error during building an application c++ using api qgis 2.8

Tags: qgis, api, c++

I have an apllication that need an object

the object type is `QgsSymbolV2`

but i cannot do that :

```
QgsSymbolV2 * lSymbol = new QgsSymbolV2();
```

because in the class qgssymbolv2 there is no constructor it is a pure static class, but in the old version ( qgsi 1.6 by example ) the class qgissymbol has 3 types of constructor with different parameters and a default constructor

so my idea is to build my class CMyQgisSymbol by exemple in order to add some fonction that my application needs but my class must be instanciate by a new  and must be based or herit of the qgssymbolv2 class

i try this code :
in my header file :

```
class CMyQgsSymbol : public QgsSymbolV2
{
public :
    CMyQgsSymbol();
    ~CMyQgsSymbol();
}
```

in my source file :

```
lSymbol = new CMyQgsSymbol();
```

but when i build the code i have this error :

```
cannot allocate an object of abstract type
```

How can I proceed to create this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent class you have some **virtual functions** and it is an abstract class (so you can't create objects from that class).

So you have to implement  them in your child class.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089083/pure-virtual-function-with-implementation) you have a nice explanation of virtual functions.

Comment: finally i use a different way, i use this : QgsSymbolV2 * newsymbol = QgsSymbolV2::defaultSymbol(QGis::GeometryType)